# Can u check why is an error coming after concatenating numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I tried Concatenating 2 numpy arrays but I got an error.
The  error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Python\Numpy\OperationsOnArrays1.py", line 28, in <module>
    array3 = np.concatenate((array,array2))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 1 has size 2
```

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([2,43,2,
                  4,1,3])



# Sorting an array by ascending order

array = np.sort(array)

# Sorting by specifying the axis

array = np.array([[2,5,4],[3,2,1]])


# array5 = np.array([[2,5,4],[3,2,1]])

array = np.sort(array,axis=1)
# Concate (adding 1 array after another)

array2 = np.zeros((4,2))
print(array2)




array3 = np.concatenate((array,array2))



print(array)
print(array2)
print(array3)
```

Comment: What are you expecting from the `concatenate`?  All the sorting is irrelevant.  What's the shape of the 2 argument arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(array.shape, array2.shape)` will print `(2, 3) (4, 2)`.

For concatenate to work, the first dimension has to be the same in all arrays.